# Google Maps doesn't work on Lumia 630

Tags: google, maps, nokia-lumia-630

As the title says, I didn't use to have any trouble with using maps.google.com with Lumia 630 but now it will first load the page VERY SLOWLY and then get stuck. It is a terribly irritating as I need Google maps to navigate through a metropolis I have moved to recently. I did change my phone provider to Vodafone a week ago but the clumsy performance with Google Maps is still there even if I use a high speed Wifi. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the supplied (Bing or Here) Maps app? These don't need to download data on the move, and in some areas, have better level of detail/accuracy.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I find Google Maps instructions more crisp and accurate.